# Java: How to keep my application functioning properly even If I'm having a game open while it's running at the background

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I know the title didnt say much, but here I go with a clearer explanation:

I have made a tool/app in netbeans that extends JFrame. It has a button and i've added a keyListener when the button is pressed. It gets if the VK_DOWN button is pressed, if yes, it presses it 4 times and then presses enter. this works very fine, but I want to use this in a game. But when I have the app running, if i click on something else, it takes away the priority (i hope thats the right word here..), it doesnt work anymore unless I click on the app and make it top priority again..

Here is the code for the button:

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jButton1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO: Do something for the keyTyped event
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO: Do something for the keyPressed event
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_L){
            System.out.println("Works");
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_DOWN){
            System.out.println("Down Arrow Pressed!");
            e.setKeyCode(e.VK_DOWN);
            e.setKeyCode(e.VK_DOWN);
            e.setKeyCode(e.VK_DOWN);
            e.setKeyCode(e.VK_DOWN);
            e.setKeyCode(e.VK_ENTER);

        }
    }
    });
}
```

I want to press the VK_DOWN arrow key in the game and let the app press it 4 times and then press enter by itself. This works only when I'm running the app on top of everything else; but if Im running the game, the game takes the higher priority and so the app dont work ..

Please help.

Comment: The word you are looking for is 'focus' only one window will have 'focus' and only it will be sent key events and the likes from the OS. It is possible, though I am not if it is with Java, to have you program look at the key state directly with out having to listen for events form the OS. I suspect the JRE might spoil your fun here though

Comment: You want the 'down arrow' key events to work in the game, or your GUI?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to java. What exactly do you mean by the GUI? Yes I want my "down arrow" key event from the game to be detected by the tool and then the tool will respond back to the keyboard and tell it what to do, in this case it tells it to setKeyCode 'down arrow' 4 times + setKeyCode 'Enter' 1 time.

Comment: It's like a keybind basically. I press "down arrow" in the game, the app should get this "down arrow" on keyPressed. And then tell my keyboard what to do, then that should be applied to the game.

Comment: GUI = Graphical User Interface, a common abbreviation. Also, you can't send key events to the keyboard, only simulate them. Again, I am not sure if Java will let you do this, but check out aglassman's answer below

Comment: I'm thinking of using WindowsEvent to see which Window is Activated. Then use this code any window that is activated. The code is fine but it doesnt work for some reason, is this even the right way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you are looking to do with Java unless you use some native code.

Comment: I'm thinking of using WindowsEvent to see which Window is Activated. Then use this code any window that is activated. The code is fine but it doesnt work for some reason, is this even the right way ?

Comment: @MirwaisMaarij Java doesn't support global key binding (or whatever you want to call it). You should use another language.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this API:

"JNativeHook is a library to provide global keyboard and mouse hooking for Java. The primary purpose is to provide a portable and reliable method for delivering keyboard and mouse events to a Java application that would otherwise be inaccessible. This is beneficial for applcatiions that run in the background but may require user interaction though hotkeys or mouse events."

http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/

Comment: This sounds like the perfect solution to the problem!

Comment: I have downloaded the source of this. So you are saying that I could bring my code from above into this and then when I'm running this nativehook whenever I press the 'down arrow' key it will simulate it 4 times like I want?

Comment: I'm thinking of using WindowsEvent to see which Window is Activated. Then use this code any window that is activated. The code is fine but it doesnt work for some reason, is this even the right way ?

Comment: You're going to have to poke around the api as I haven't used it.  I think it should be able to do what you want, sorry I can't help you more that that!

Answer (score 0):

Uh, not sure whether it will work, but try the Robot class from awt package to generate your Key-Events. It shall work better than your code.